# What is the one eyed mask in Noragami?

Tags: noragami

[image]

I've noticed this mask being used by almost every major antagonist in the anime. It's mostly used by them as some sort of a gateway to call the Phantoms (*Ayakashi*) but what exactly is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The masks are a medium that utilises the power of Hell to call forth Ayakashi and they basically materialise Izanami's power in our world. The masks are created by [Fujisaki Kouto](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Fujisaki_Kouto), Yato's father. The are created using the power of the Yomi no Kotonoha (Words of Hell), which are used through paint brushes that utilise the power of [Izanami](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Izanami). He currently possesses two brushes, his own and Ebisu's. The ability the brushes provide are of course masks summoning and the control over Ayakashi.

> Masks Summoning: An ability she obtains from using the Mandate of Hell (Phantom Brush). She is able to summon phantoms without chanting or affixing a mask, and without sustaining blight in the process, unlike Ebisu.